# Talend: save oracle input to global variable

Tags: java, talend

[image]

Hey there, 
as you may see, I am trying to get data out of an Oracle DB. It is only one row, I am trying to iterate over and to save the data into a global variable. This global variable is in my case a "list of values" in my context variables. With the tJavaFlex, I want to save the variables into a `local java.util.ArrayList` (called "list" in my case) and in the end code part i want to make an action like "`globalMap.put(context.myListOfVariables, list);`"

The problem I am stuck on is, that my main code looks like this:
`list.add(row1.TestData);`

I have no idea, how to make a limit for the loop in the main code. Is it possible to get the number of rows or is there a variable like `tOracleInput_1_HAS_NEXT`?
I want to make the loop first, to fill my "list" and only after the whole loop i want to run the `globalMap.put()`-function.

Now the `put()`-function is called as often as my list is adding an item.

Sorry for my bad english, hope you can get my problem and help me :)

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I deleted the tFlowToIterate.